# Windows PortProxy Issue After restart PC

Tags: windows, port-forwarding, reboot, netsh

I am using Windows, and problems occur on some PCs regardless of the OS.

I added proxy information through:

```
netsh interface add ...
```

and it applied successfully and connected successfully.

I checked through

```
netsh interface portproxy show v4tov4
```

But sometimes, after reboot my computer, Port-Forwarding does not work anymore.

I checked windows event log and saw nothing...

When this problem occurs, if I restart the "IP Helper" Service, the situation return from abnormal to normal ( connect success ),

I want to know why it is not working?

I have tried to find information about this problem on Google, but there is no answer...